# Mysql after insert trigger inserting 1st row twice

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql work bench. I have two tables "new_machine"(parent table) and "machine_record" (child table). I am using after insert trigger to insert m_id and m_name from new_machine table to mac_id and mac_name from machine_record table.

m_id is primary key for new_machine.
m_id and m_name from new_machine table is foreign key to mac_id and mac_name from machine_record table.

when i insert data in new_machine it populates in machine_record but the first record entered is entered twice.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `system_data`.`new_machine_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `new_machine` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `system_data`.`machine_record` (mac_id, mac_name)
select m_id, m_name
from `system_data`.`new_machine`;
END
```

Comment: Can u post the schema for ur tables?

Answer (score 0):

you can direct use the Values from your insert on new_machines. So
it is not necessary to get it with a SELECT. Also your
SELECT selects ALL Records from new_machines.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `system_data`.`new_machine_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `new_machine` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `system_data`.`machine_record` (mac_id, mac_name)
  VALUES (NEW.m_id, NEW.m_name);
END
```